# How to solve missing declaration of activity 'MainActivity' in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android-studio

[image]

I am getting this error in all of my project: `the activity 'MainActivity(4) is not declared in Android Manifest.xml`

This is my code so far:

```
package com.efekanfiliz.methodclasses;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstantState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstantState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

testMethod();
}
int x;

private void testMethod(){x=4+4;}
}
```

i couldn't solve this no matter what i did and i could not understand the cause of it as well.

Comment: "i am writing this to fill character limit:" <- Well, you shouldn't have. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - If you simply would have added your code and a little bit of problem description you could have easily reached the limit.

Comment: can you delete your dislike,i cant ask new questions because of your dislike,the reason why i asked this question in a bad way because i am new on this website and i dont know how to ask a good question,i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Double-click the manifests and you should see something like:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

If you don't see it, just copy paste it between the `<application>` tags.

Comment: i did what you said and got an error like this Class referenced in the manifest, `com.example.efekanfiliz.methodsandclasses.MainActivity`, was not found in the project or the libraries

Comment: just delete ".methodsandclasses"